# Does solidity interpret 1e18 as 1,000,000,000,000,000,000 or as 1.000000000000000000?

Tags: decimals

Say I have a super simple function like the following one which just returns 1e18. If I test this in remix I get 1000000000000000000. But I'm second guessing myself because I am new to this and I am looking at a contract where they set a variable to 1e18 (without later dividing by 1e18) where I know they don't mean 10^18.

I am correct in my understanding that if you intend a variable to be equal to 1, and you set it to 1e18, you later need to divide by 1e18 (sounds incredibly obvious but there is no way for me to see more deeply how solidity interprets 1e18)?

```
function returnValue public returns(uint256) {
return 1e18;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right in your understanding. Basically, Ethereum and Blockchain in general, use **fixed-point arithmetic** instead of **floating-point arithmetic** for deterministic execution. Thus, the blockchain itself cannot handle **float** number, i.e., 1.2, 2.4.

As a consequence, Ethereum and Solidity language need to define a rule to handle fractional numbers and ensuring precision in token values. And, they call it "wei". There are 10^18 (1 followed by 18 zeros) wei in one Ether. Using 18 decimal places allows for precise representation of fractional amounts of Ether. Therefore, it provides a level of granularity that can be beneficial in various scenarios, particularly in the financial and decentralized finance (DeFi) sectors where precision is paramount

Answer (score 0):

regardless of blockchain, 1e18 notation means 1 billion-billion, yes, 10 to the power of 18, yes if each person out of 9 billion people had 9 billion dollars themselves then we would have 18 billion-billion dollars on Earth.

an ether is a unit which is equal to 1e18 wei, wei being the smallest unit, an "atom" (from Ancient Greek ἄτομος, átomos, "indivisible")

anecdotally one ether is ~$2,300 right now, so one wei is worth ~2,300 / 1e18 = $2.3e-15, just to paint a picture of the much higher resolution blockchains have compared to traditional finance.